# How can I make proper use of subvolumes in btrfs?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, btrfs

In the past, I've always used three `ext4` partitions to fulfill my needs:

- `/dev/sda2`: `/`
- `/dev/sda3`: `/home`
- `/dev/sda4`: `/mnt/Data`

Right now, I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 with the `btrfs` filesystem. After installing, I ended up with one big partition, containing the three partitions:

- `/dev/sda2`: *extended*

  - `/dev/sda5`: `/`
  - `/dev/sda6`: `/home`
  - `/dev/sda7`: `/mnt/Data`

When I browse through these partitions from a live USB, something strange happens: the root directory of each of these partitions is called `@`. I suspect that this has something to do with something called *subvolumes* in `btrfs`.

I'd like to make good use of those subvolumes. For instance, I'm using a separate `/home` partition to make new installs easier. Is this still necessary? Or may I just as well put every partition in one big partition with different subvolumes to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on exactly what you want to do with your disks, but in my case **yes** I moved to using btrfs and I have done exactly as you say - **use subvolumes instead of partitions**.

---

*From [the btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Subvolumes):*

> A subvolume in btrfs is not the same as an LVM logical volume or a ZFS
>   subvolume. With LVM, a logical volume is a block device in its own
>   right (which could for example contain any other filesystem or
>   container like dm-crypt, MD RAID, etc.) - this is not the case with
>   btrfs.
>
> A btrfs subvolume is not a block device (and cannot be treated as one)
>   instead, a btrfs subvolume can be thought of as a POSIX file
>   namespace. This namespace can be accessed via the top-level subvolume
>   of the filesystem, or it can be mounted in its own right.
>
> So, given a filesystem structure like this:
>
> ```
> toplevel
> +-- dir_1           (normal directory)
> |   +-- file_2      (normal file)
> |   \-- file_3      (normal file)
> \-- subvol_a        (subvolume)
>     +-- subvol_b    (subvolume, nested below subvol_a)
>     |   \-- file_4  (normal file)
>     \-- file_5      (normal file)
> ```
>
> The top-level subvolume (ID5) (which one can think of as the root of
>   the filesystem) can be mounted, and the full filesystem structure will
>   be seen at the mount point; alternatively any other subvolume can be
>   mounted (with the mount options subvol or subvolid, for example
>   subvol=subvol_a) and only anything below that subvolume (in the above
>   example the subvolume subvol_b, it's contents, and file file_4) will
>   be visible at the mount point.
>
> Subvolumes can be nested and each subvolume (except the top-level
>   subolume) has a parent subvolume. Mounting a subvolume also makes any
>   of its nested child subvolumes available at their respective location
>   relative to the mountpoint.
>
> A btrfs filesystem has a default subvolume, which is initially set to
>   be the top-level subvolume and which is mounted if no subvol or
>   subvolid option is specified.
>
> Changing the default subvolume with btrfs subvolume default will make
>   the top level of the filesystem inaccessible, except by use of the
>   subvol=/ or subvolid=5 mount options.
>
> Subvolumes can be moved around in the filesystem.

---

My understanding is that the Ubuntu installer (if you choose btrfs) will create `@` and `@home` as subvolumes in your btrfs filesystem. It will then mount `@` as the filesystem root, and `@home` in `/home`.

This then opens up more possibilities, one of which is snapshots. I use `apt-btrfs-snapshot` which manages creating a snapshot each time I do anything with `apt`, i.e. installing or removing packages. In this way I can revert all changes to the system if something goes wrong. I also have subvolumes for each of the users on my system, although this is almost definitely unnecessary. The point is that I no longer have separate root and home partitions, and don't waste space trying to allocate enough to each.

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10 over the top of a 14.04 install which had btrfs for the main disk - and I was able to keep the `@home` subvolume intact while replacing the root `@` directory with the new install just using the graphical installer. This was the main reason for using separate partitions, and it seems that recent Ubuntu versions support btrfs in the same way - so I would suggest that you no longer need partitions if you've configured btrfs.